# include LICENSE and copyright NOTICE files in sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

Suppose I have a project that uses a third-party library, e.g. [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) which is published under an MIT license.

When using [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) to generate a distributable tarball, zip, deb, etc. I am redistributing a copy of all of my dependencies. When redistributing, I am required, by the licensing conditions of my dependencies, to include a copy of that license / copyright notice / licensing conditions (in the license usually called *redistribution in binary form*). By the way, sbt-native-packager also includes a copy of the Scala standard library as well, which also does not include the appropriate licensing conditions / copyright notice according to its 3-clause BSD style license.

By default, sbt-native-packager does not include such license copies / copyright notices / ... in the generated distribution.

**What I am looking for is a convenient way to automatically include all licenses / copyright notices of all (including transitive) dependencies.**

*... or else, I suppose, I would be breaking the law if I published the raw tarball generated by sbt-native-packager as is on e.g. the GitHub release page, wouldn't I?*

---

## edit

I guess, it would be really hard to have a general way for sbt-native-packager to inject all licenses/copyright notices into the distributions created by it, because neither the jar archive nor ivy, maven, sbt, etc. have first class support for adding the license and copyright notice to the archive.

The only recommendation I have seen thus far is by the Apache Software Foundation. They recommend to [put the license at the top of the jar archive](http://www.apache.org/dev/apply-license.html#new) (cointaining the bare license file) and [include a NOTICE file as well](http://www.apache.org/legal/src-headers.html#notice) (containing all the copyright notices). I deem this recommendation good.

I guess, support for handling all this legal stuff should be better to begin with. Build tools like sbt should support this better and much more visible, e.g. check all generated jar archives and if they do not include **both** LICENSE and NOTICE files error out of tasks like package.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: there's AFAIK no way of handling licences in a general way in sbt-native-packager. E.g. putting them in a separate directory or listing them.

Having said that, I think that this is not really necessary for a couple of reasons. I'm no advocate, so this is just my understanding of this.

1. If you have your git tarball there is none of your dependencies included. Only a build file that declares them. So you are not distributing any code. So this should be fine
2. When you build an executable binary the you will include not only the code, but the whole jar, which normally includes all licenese and copyright hints. Technically you have included everything.

I haven't seen any issues around that topic or a way other build tools like maven/gradle handle this. What would a solution look like? If this is a problem?

#### Update

I found this [sbt-license-report plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-license-report) which should generate the information you need. If this is what you are looking for, I'm happy to merge a pull request updating the sbt-native-packager docs :)

Comment: To your reason #2: I have inspected the jars, there are neither license files nor copyright notices included.